# Set An Unknown Number of Variables That areParsed From Each Line of a Text File

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, variables, cmd

Apologies for my poorly worded question and my scatterbrain workings.  Essentially I want to set an unknown number of variables that are parsed from each line of a text file.

I have written batch file to create symbolic links for network shares to a `C:\Volumes` folder.

```
@echo off
echo:
set /p dest=ENTER FOLDER PATH: 
set dest="%dest%"
net use %dest%
if not exist "C:\Volumes" MD "C:\Volumes"
for %%i in (%dest%) do (set "fold=%%~ni")
mklink /d "c:\VOLUMES\%fold%" "%dest%"
pause
```

What I want to try is the same theory but have the script point at a text file `mounts.txt` with a list of folder paths and for a for loop to cycle through the list make a symbolic link for each path in the list.  I have toyed with counters and cannot get it working correctly. I don't think I am going about it the right way at all.

Contents of `mounts.txt`

```
\\10.19.10.238\Masters\Removed bin\Work here
\\10.19.10.241\Scanning\WIP\to process
```

This does not work:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set i=1
:add
Set /a "i+=1"
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in  (mounts.txt) do  (set dest%i%=%%A)
if exist %dest%%i% goto:add
echo %dest%
echo %dest%%i%
echo !dest!
echo !dest!%i%
pause
```

Nor this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set i=0
For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=] EOL=" %%A In ('Find /N /V ""^<"mounts.txt"') Do (
   set /a i=i+1
   set "dest!i!=%%B"
)
For /l %%a in (1,1,4) do echo _dest%%a is !dest%%a!
For /l %%a in (1,1,4) do set dest%%a=!dest%%a!
echo !dest!
pause
```

I did get something like this to work to an extent but cannot figure out how to use the `dest[1]`, `dest[2]` as variables in other processes further down in the script.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set counter=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%a In (mounts.txt) do (
  set /a counter+=1
  set "dest[!counter!]=%%a"
)
set dest[
```

And the list could be added to with many more.  If `%dest%n` variables can be set, the use the same theory to set different `%fold%` variables based on each `%dest%n` then maybe the links can be set using the same process as the original script.

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If your question actually describes what you want to do, you don't need to set variables. Just use the lines from the text file with a `for /f` loop:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (mount.txt) do mklink /d "C:\VOLUMES\%%~ni" "%%i"
```

It's safer to quote the filename, especially if you want/need to use the FQFN. Therefore you need the `usebackq` option, else a quoted string will be processed as a string, not a filename:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("C:\full path\mount.txt") do mklink /d "C:\VOLUMES\%%~ni" "%%i"
```

Comment: I feel so silly.  This is a much simpler solution.  I had as much as `for /f %%a in (mount.txt) do echo %%a` I don't know why I complicate things.   I do have to put the full path to the txt file as it needs to be ran as administrator.  This is the answer to my question but not the question I asked.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @roar: please see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

You seemingly want to dynamically set the variables as dummy array's and return results based on the line numbers. If so, use the counter you created to become the max of the `for /L` loop, here is an example by just `echo`ing the results:

```
@echo off & set cnt=0
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("mounts.txt") do (
    set /a cnt+=1
    set "var[!cnt!]=%%i"
)
for /L %%a in (1,1,!cnt!) do echo !var[%%a]!
```

**Edit**

As highlighted by @Compo in the comments; after the initial code block where we increment the `%cnt%` variable, we no longer require using `delayedexpansion` on the `%cnt%` variable specifically and can therefore use `%cnt%` instead of `!cnt!`:

```
@echo off & set cnt=0
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("mounts.txt") do (
    set /a cnt+=1
    set "var[!cnt!]=%%i"
)
for /L %%a in (1,1,%cnt%) do echo !var[%%a]!
```

Comment: This is a closer answer to the question but Stephan's answer is the solution I need.  I did try utilize your code though and while it did set many variables I was unsure how to use them later on in the code.  I tried to do something like  `for %%i in (!var[%%a]!) do (set fold=%%~ni)` to try parse the final folder as a variable, but that obviously was not correct.  Is it possible out of interest?

Comment: I've upvoted this because it wisely uses `UseBackQ`, and double-quotes to allow for any modified list file name or within its potentially included path, contain possible problem characters. Also for technically showing a method of assigning each to an incremented variable naming scheme, as requested within the question. The only thing I would add, for information purposes, which doesn't detract from the code or its functionality, is that `!cnt!` here, `(1,1,!cnt!)`, is not longer modified, as it is outside of the loop, so could return to using the standard `%` characters, i.e. `(1,1,%cnt%)`.

Comment: Thanks, @Compo. Sure, I fully agree. I do this out of habit when using `setlocal` based on the way we define scope in `perl` which I use daily as well, but will update the answer accordingly as I think it is important future readers understand where `delayedexpansion` fits in.

Comment: @roar, although unnecessary, have you tried creating additional variables within the `for /f` loop, so that you do not need to add a further `for` loop later. For example replace `set "var[!cnt!]=%%i"` with two lines `set "spath[!cnt!]=%%i"` and `set "sname[!cnt!]=%%~nxi"`. Then you could use them directly in the `for /l` loop replacing `echo !var[%%a]!` with `mklink /D "C:\VOLUMES\!sname[%%a]!" "!spath[%%a]!"`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a courtesy example, just to show you how you could have still used `find.exe`, as in one of your examples, and additionally includes a different method of iterating the variables with unknown increments:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

Rem The next line ensures that there are no variables defined with names beginning _
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set _) 2>NUL"') Do Set "%%G="

Rem The next lines parse the directory paths content file and defines the incrementing variables
For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=]" %%G In (
    '"%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /N "\" 0< "C:\Users\roar\My Directory\mounts.txt" 2>NUL"'
) Do (
    Set "_Path%%G]=%%H"
    Set "_Name%%G]=%%~nxH"
)

Rem The next lines iterate the defined variables beginning _Path[ and runs commands against them
For /F "Tokens=2 Delims=[]" %%G In ('"(Set _Path[) 2>NUL"') Do (
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    MkLink /D "C:\Volumes\!_Name[%%G]!" "!_Path[%%G]!"
    EndLocal
)

Rem The next line undefines any previously defined variables named beginning with _
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set _) 2>NUL"') Do Set "%%G="
```

*Please note that is likely you may need to run this script elevated, in order for the `MkLink` command to create the symbolic links.*